# ¿Cómo hacer una tabla MYSQL con una columna autoincrement y otra con primary key?

Tags: mysql

¿Cómo puedo hacer que en una tabla en MySQL tenga una columna auto incrementable y otra sea llave primaria?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Sinventario
(
BASE_AUTOINCREMENT AUTO_INCREMENT,
   FI_CODIGO VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   FI_DESCRIPCION VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
   FI_CATEGORIA VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   FI_DESCRIPCIONDETALLADA VARCHAR(50),
   FI_VENDEDOR VARCHAR(30),
   FI_STATUS BOOLEAN,
   FI_UNIDAD VARCHAR(30)
);
```

Necesito que `BASE_AUTOINCREMENT` sea Auto incrementable y `FI_CODIGO` sea Llave Primaria.

Comment: por que querrías tener una columna auto incrementable que no sea la primary key? no tiene mucho sentido, pues el valor seria inconsistente entre una instalación y otra. Considera que un autoincrementable es un dato opaco que no tiene ralacion con los datos del registro, solo se usa para relacionar tablas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo diría que la primera columna `BASE_AUTOINCREMENT` debería ser la llave primaria y con `AUTO_INCREMENT` y que dicha columna sirva para la relación con otras tablas. Mientras que tu columna `F1_CODIGO` debería ser `UNIQUE INDEX` para que no admita valores repetidos y que puedas realizar búsquedas directas sobre dicha columna.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Sinventario (
    BASE_AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FI_CODIGO VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    FI_DESCRIPCION VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    FI_CATEGORIA VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    FI_DESCRIPCIONDETALLADA VARCHAR(50),
    FI_VENDEDOR VARCHAR(30),
    FI_STATUS BOOLEAN,
    FI_UNIDAD VARCHAR(30),
    UNIQUE KEY(F1_CODIGO)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

por que la base_autoincrement es la cantidad simple de registros y la otra es el codigo donde relaciono varias tablas.. lo que hice fue asignar indice base_autoincrement y llave primaria FI_CODIGO

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Sinventario
(
BASE_AUTOINCREMENT INT NOT NULL,
   FI_CODIGO VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   FI_DESCRIPCION VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
   FI_CATEGORIA VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   FI_DESCRIPCIONDETALLADA VARCHAR(50),
   FI_VENDEDOR VARCHAR(30),
   FI_STATUS BOOLEAN,
   FI_UNIDAD VARCHAR(30),
   PRIMARY KEY (FI_CODIGO), INDEX (BASE_AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

Comment: que es la "cantidad simple de registros"?